# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a connection to my database in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio edition from Visual Studio 2008.

I stored a procedure called "CTable" in my database and I want to execute it (from Visual Studio).

This is my code:

```
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = "Server=(local);Database=dbAjout;Integrated Security=True"

    Dim MyConn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    MyConn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    Dim query As String = "EXEC CTable"

    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, MyConn)

    MyConn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MyConn.Close()
End Sub
```

but I have this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information:

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

What do you suggest to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You open your connection twice. As per documentation ([`SqlConnection.Open()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open.aspx)):

> **Exceptions**
>   InvalidOperationException
>    - Cannot open a connection without specifying a data source or server.
>    - or
>    - The connection is already open.

That is (probably) what causes the `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown.

Comment: @user2550171 You call the `Open` method twice on `MyConn`, which results in this exception. Because you have already opened the connection. You can remove either one of them to fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
Dim strConn As String
strConn = "Server=(local);Database=dbAjout;Integrated Security=True"

Dim MyConn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
Dim cmd As SqlCommand

Dim query As String = "EXEC CTable"

cmd = New SqlCommand(query, MyConn)

MyConn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
MyConn.Close()
```

You should consider the invoking the `Dispose` pattern for your `SqlConnection` by utilizing the `Using` statement, like this:

```
Dim strConn As String
strConn = "Server=(local);Database=dbAjout;Integrated Security=True"

Using MyConn As New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    Dim query As String = "EXEC CTable"

    cmd = New SqlCommand(query, MyConn)

    MyConn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Note: The `Using` statement can be applied to any object that implements the `IDisposable` interface. In this case it will automatically close the `SqlConnection` object by calling the `Close` method for you. Behind the scenes, the VB.NET compiler will see the `Using` statement and wrap the `Using` block in a `Try` block and give it a `Finally` block, which is where the `SqlConnection`'s `Close` method will be invoked on your behalf. This syntax makes the code easier to read in my opinion, easier to maintain as you can see everything that is contained within the connection object and removes the need to 'remember' to close the underlying database connection.