# "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll" visual studio vb.net using database microsoft access

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

im a beginner in vb.net and when i start my coding the error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll" i dont know what to do. this is my code.

```
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [login] WHERE [ID] & [Password] =" & TextBoxUsername.Text & TextBoxPassword.Text & "", myConnection)

    myConnection.Open() '*its keep pointing at this* 

    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim userFound As Boolean
    Dim userID As String = ""
    Dim UserPassword As String = ""
    While dr.Read
        userFound = True
        userID = dr("ID").ToString
        UserPassword = dr("Password").ToString
        Form2.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End While
    If userFound = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username/Password")
        'Button","User Validation", MessageBoxButton.OK , MessageBoxIcon.Error)'
    End If
    myConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class**

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475839/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexception-occurred-in-sy)

Comment: Please read [mcve] and the section at its bottom about how to debug small programs.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't currently wrapping your parameters in single quotes and your WHERE clause syntax appears to be off. It's likely you want something like this :

```
"SELECT * FROM [login] WHERE [ID] = '" & TextBoxUsername.Text & "' AND [Password] = '" & TextBoxPassword.Text & "'"
```

A larger issue here is that you should be using parameters to build your query, which can not only help you avoid issues like this, but it can also help prevent nasty things like SQL Injection :

```
' Build your connection ' 
Using(Dim myConnection As New OleDbConnection("{your-connection-string"}))
    ' Use parameters in your query '
    Dim query = "SELECT * FROM [login] WHERE [ID] = ? AND Password = ?"
    ' Build your command to execute '
    Using(Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand(query, myConnection))
         ' Open your connection '
         myConnection.Open()
         ' Add your parameters (these will replace the ? in your query)
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",TextBoxUsername.Text)
         myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",TextBoxPassword.Text)
         Using(Dim myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
              If myReader.HasRows Then
                   ' Do stuff '
                   userFound = True
                   userID = dr("ID").ToString
                   UserPassword = dr("Password").ToString
                   Form2.Show()
                   Me.Hide()
              Else
                   ' Do other stuff '
                   MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username/Password")
              End If
         End Using
    End Using
End Using
```