# vb.net // Failed to connect to the database ? Login System Check the user if admin or not

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

*Hello guys, I am implementing a login system where there are two users it's either the admin or the superadmin, however it always fail to connect to the database. I'm kinda new to VB.net and I'm trying to figure out on how this make thing work and yep I searched up the web on how to create on but it fails, and btw here's the error log generated after logging in*

> Failed to Connect to the Database
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Public Class LoginFrm

    Private Sub LoginBtn_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginBtn.Click
        If userBox.Text = "" Or passwordBox.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password are blank", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
            conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ResortReservationSystem.accdb"

            Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM userTable WHERE userName='" & userBox.Text & "' AND passWord = '" & passwordBox.Text & "'"
            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql)
            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            sqlCom.Connection.Open()
            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()
            If sqlRead.Item("userType") = "SuperAdmin" Then
                welcomeFrm.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
            If sqlRead.Item("userType") = "Admin" Then
                manageEmployeeForm.Show()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match.", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                userBox.Text = ""
                passwordBox.Text = ""
                userBox.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

> Edit: I have fixed some issues and now I am encountering this,
> No data exists for the row/column. For what I know, .Item is to get the fetch the data, but it seems like it doesnt work for me.
> table name: userTable
> fields:  userName, passWord, userType
> datas:   John, Doe, SuperAdmin

Comment: Um, that message is the one you wrote, so it is of little value to us. What is the message from the system?

Comment: @jmcilhinney A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
that's the error log that I got.

Comment: see this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475839/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-invalidoperationexception-occurred-in-sy

Answer (score 0):

The point of a data reader is to read data. If you have done any reading on data readers and their use then you know that you have to call the `Read` method to actually read a record. You aren't calling `Read`, hence there's no data in your data reader.

Answer (score 0):

1. `If userBox.Text = "" Or passwordBox.Text = "" Then`
   Change the `Or` to `OrElse` to short circuit the If.
2. Connections and commands need to be closed and disposed. A `Using...End Using` block will do this for you even if there is an error.
3. You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Likewise, pass the command text and connection directly to the constructor of the command.
4. Never concatenate strings with user input to build sql statements. You risk sql injection which can ruin your database. It also makes the sql statement easier to write because you don't have to use all those single and double quote and ampersands.
5. You are only using a single piece of data so don't return all the fields. You only need userType.
6. Always use parameters. Access (OleDb) does not care about the name of the parameter. I just use appropriate names for readability. What is important is the order that the parameter appears in the sql statement must match the order that the parameter is added to the parameters collection. I had to guess at the datatype and field size of the parameters. Check your database for the real values and correct the code accordingly.
7. Since we are only getting a single piece of data, we can use `.ExecuteScalar` which returns the first column of the first row of the result set.
8. The `End Using` closes and disposes the connection and command so now we can mess with returned data.

**Sidenote:** Your problem was that a reader does not start reading the returned rows until you call reader.Read. This is no longer relevant since we are not using a reader.

```
Private Sub LoginBtn_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginBtn.Click
    Dim AdminType As String
    If userBox.Text = "" OrElse passwordBox.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Username and password must be filled in.", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        Using conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\ResortReservationSystem.accdb"),
                sqlCom As New OleDbCommand("SELECT userType FROM userTable WHERE userName= @User AND passWord = @Password", conn)
            With sqlCom.Parameters
                .Add("@User", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = userBox.Text
                .Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = passwordBox.Text
            End With
            conn.Open()
            AdminType = sqlCom.ExecuteScalar.ToString
        End Using
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(AdminType) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match.", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            userBox.Text = ""
            passwordBox.Text = ""
            userBox.Focus()
        ElseIf AdminType = "SuperAdmin" Then
            welcomeFrm.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf AdminType = "Admin" Then
            manageEmployeeForm.Show()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```